# ZF1: unit testing of authentication functionality

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework

I am new to unit-testing and trying to implement first set of tests for Index controller in Zend Framework 1 application.

In this controller I have a login action that uses Zend_Auth for checking provided user's credentials. I don't quite understand what is the best way to test it:

1. Create separate test database config. Before making any tests upload SQL file with initial state of the database and set this test database as a default database.
2. Redefine (somehow) Zend_Auth so that it always return predefined array with user information (or empty array) and test this scenario. I found this implementation in Zend Framework 2, but no for version 1.

I would appreciate any advice and links to projects in ZF1 that have unit testing for authentication and functionality connected with database in general.

---

UPD

Here is a login action of Index Controller that I'm going to test

```
public function loginAction()
{

    $loginForm = new Form_Login();
    $modelUser = new Model_User();

    $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    $flashMessenger = $this->_helper->getHelper('FlashMessenger');

    if(!empty($formData)){

        if($loginForm->isValid($formData)){

            $authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter());

            $authAdapter->setTableName('user')
                ->setIdentityColumn('email')
                ->setCredentialColumn('password')
                ->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?)');

            $authAdapter->setIdentity($formData['form_email']);
            $authAdapter->setCredential($formData['form_password']);

            $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

            $result = $auth->authenticate($authAdapter);

            if($result->isValid()) {

                $userData = $authAdapter->getResultRowObject();
                $modelUser->setTimestamp($userData->user_id);
                $this->_processLoggedInUser($userData);

            } else {
                $loginForm->addError("Incorrect email/password");
            }
        }

    }

    //Retrieve Facebook App ID
    $this->view->facebookAppId = Zend_Registry::get('facebookAppId');
    $this->view->googleClientId = Zend_Registry::get('googleClientId');
    $this->view->loginForm = $loginForm;
    $this->view->userMsg = $flashMessenger->getMessages();
}
```

So, I thought, maybe I can use Zend_Test_DbAdapter, set it as a default adapter and make it to return predefined set of data?

Comment: Post some code to see what you have so far. If you have implemented a dependency injection design pattern you can mock(aka simulate) the behavior of your classes

Comment: Did you tried this: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.test.phpunit.html#zend.test.phpunit.loginexample

Comment: @KA_lin I just posted code of login function. Also I read about Zend_Test_DbAdapter. Not sure if I can use it in this case?

Comment: Well you should avoid creating objects in the loginAction method because you can't simulate it's behaviour. Declare $authAdapter and $auth in the contructor. http://php-di.org/doc/frameworks/zf1.html

Answer (score 1):

I've found out 2 ways to work with db data during unit tests:

1.

```
public function testStudentLogin()
{
    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH."/configs/application.ini", APPLICATION_ENV);
    $testDatabaseConfig = $config->testDb;
    $connection = Zend_Db::factory($testDatabaseConfig);

    Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($adapter);

    $this->request->setMethod('POST');
    $this->request->setPost(array('form_email' => 'student', 'form_password' => '123'));
    $this->dispatch('/index/login');
    $this->assertController('index');
    $this->assertAction('login');
    $this->assertRedirect('/index/student-professor');
}
```

So, here you store test db credentials in application.ini. Then you initialise connection to it through adapter and change Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter.

2.

```
public function testStudentLogin()
{
    $adapter   = new Zend_Test_DbAdapter();
    $stmt1Rows = array(array('user_id' => 1, 'email' => 'student', 'password' => '202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70', 'user_type' => 'consumer', 'zend_auth_credential_match' => 1));
    $stmt1     = Zend_Test_DbStatement::createSelectStatement($stmt1Rows);
    $adapter->appendStatementToStack($stmt1);

    $this->request->setMethod('POST');
    $this->request->setPost(array('form_email' => 'student', 'form_password' => '123'));
    $this->dispatch('/index/login');
    $this->assertController('index');
    $this->assertAction('login');
    $this->assertRedirect('/index/student-professor');
}
```

Here you use Zend_Test_DbAdapter where you can predefine what data will be returned. I think that using separate database for test purpose makes your code cleaner, so I'll probably use this approach. If you have other ideas/best practices let me know

Comment: IIRC the application environment should be "TEST" so that automatically the test database can be used.